# Css Bug in Prestashop cause quick view miss

Tags: css, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

When I use default theme, I want to change container width to 100% on **global.css**  in line around line 990:

Before:

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
.container {
max-width: 117022px; }
```

after:

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
.container {
max-width: 100%; }
```

Then the partis missing. How to fix it ? Thanks

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't change styles for classes that are used on so many elements. If you want to have full width container use bootstraps `container-fluid` class instead of `container` for the element you want to be full width